# is it possible to get `RecyclerView` from Fragment?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, kotlin, android-framelayout

trying to get `RecyclerView` from this layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".listFragment">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/recyclee">
</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
```

into main activity class :

```
    private var mBlogList = findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.recyclee)
```

getting error :
`java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.Window$Callback android.view.Window.getCallback()' on a null object reference`
any help please :)

**edit 1**

i use kotlin extension now

```
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_list.*
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
private lateinit var mBlogList : RecyclerView
```

in onCreate method :

```
        mBlogList = recyclee
```

but the same error still exist

**edit 2**
listFragment code :

```
class listFragment : Fragment() {

override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list, container, false)
}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    recyclee != null
}
companion object {
    fun newInstance(): listFragment = listFragment()
}
}
```

**edit 3** 
whole MainActivity code:

```
//this app supposed to read from FirebaseDatabase
//into Recycler view
//the RecyclerView is into Fragment layout
//i use Fragments into FrameLayout in the activity_main.xml
// the RecyclerView should be shown when navigatoinBar is clicked
//or on start of MainActivity
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private var mDatabase:DatabaseReference? = null
    private lateinit var mBlogList : RecyclerView
    private var query:Query?=null
    private var options:FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Blog>?=null
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        //start listFragment , RecyclerView is there
        val mFragment = listFragment.newInstance()
        //openFragment method is below
        openFragment(mFragment)
        //navigation bottom onclicklistener


navBar.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener)
        //get data from database
        mDatabase=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("mall")
        mDatabase?.keepSynced(true)
        //here i should have recyclee but it is null i don't know why
        mBlogList = recyclee
        mBlogList.setHasFixedSize(true)
        mBlogList.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        //query of database
        query = mDatabase?.orderByKey()

    }
private val mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener = BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener { item ->
   //there are 4 icons in the navigation_bottom_bar 
    //now we are talking about listNav icon only because it is realted 
    // with listFragment
    when (item.itemId) {
        R.id.listNav -> {
            val mFragment = listFragment.newInstance()
            openFragment(mFragment)
            return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
        }
        R.id.cartNav -> {
            val mFragment = cartFragment.newInstance()
            openFragment(mFragment)
            return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
        }
        R.id.supportNav -> {
            val mFragment = supportFragment.newInstance()
            openFragment(mFragment)
            return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
        }
        R.id.accountNav -> {
            val mFragment = accountFragment.newInstance()
            openFragment(mFragment)
            return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
        }
    }
    false
}
private fun openFragment(fragment: Fragment) {
    //open Fragment into FrameLayout in the main_activity.xml
    val transaction = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
    transaction.replace(R.id.mainFrame, fragment)
    transaction.addToBackStack(null)
    transaction.commit()
}

override fun onStart() {
    super.onStart()
    //set options for FirebaseRecyclerAdapter
    options = FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Blog>()
            .setQuery(query!!, Blog::class.java)
            .build()
    //set custom adapter
    val mAdapter = object : FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Blog, BlogViewHolder>(
            options!!) {
        override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): BlogViewHolder {
            val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
                    .inflate(R.layout.cardview, parent, false)
            return BlogViewHolder(view)}

        override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: BlogViewHolder, position: Int, model: Blog) {
            holder.setTitle(model.title)
            holder.setDes(model.des)
            holder.setImage(applicationContext, model.image)
        }
    }
    mBlogList.adapter = mAdapter
}
inner class BlogViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
    var mView:View= itemView
    //set title, des amd image with data we got from database
    fun setTitle(title:String){
        var postTitle = mView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.post_title)
        postTitle?.text = title
    }
    fun setDes(des:String){
        var postDes = mView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.post_des)
        postDes?.text = des
    }
    fun setImage(image:String){
        var postImage = mView.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.post_title)
        Picasso.get().load(image).into(postImage)
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Simple answer, don't touch FragmentViews from inside the ActivityHost, do all logics inside the Fragments, not recommended answer, from inside the Fragment, inject the View at the Activity, but it will look like out of the lifecycle of the Activity since it will only be able to touch the view AFTER it has been set from the fragment, so its better to keep the logic inside the Fragment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you apply `kotlin-android-extensions` plugin then you don't need to use `findViewById` anymore because you can access views in the layout as if they're properties (by name). So, your `onCreate` could look as follows:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    assert recyclee != null
}
```

**Edit**

Since you're trying to do this in `Fragment` and your layout file is called 
 `fragment_List.xml` then in your `Fragment` you must inflate the layout first and then you can access your `RecyclerView` as in the example above for `Activity`:

```
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_List, container, false)
} 

override fun onViewCreated(view: View?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    assert recyclee != null
}
```

If you try to access your `RecyclerView` in `Activity` before `fragment_List` is inflated in the `Fragment` then it will obviously be `null` (it hasn't been created yet). That's actually what you're trying to do in `onCreate` - it's too early as the `Fragment's` layout hasn't been built yet.

**Edit 2**

As it's seen from your code, `mBlogList = recyclee` is set in `onCreate`. Even though it's done after the `ListFragment` is created, it's still too early as its `onCreateView` hasn't been called yet and so no layout is in place.

A quick fix would be to do it in `onStart` as at that point `ListFragment` is definitely there. *However, a better approach is to do the logic inside `ListFragment` itself and communicate with `MainActivity` via callbacks as described [here](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating)*

Comment: @evals what are you getting then?

Comment: java.lang.IllegalStateException: recyclee must not be null

Comment: @evals do you extend `AppCompatActivity`? Is your provided layout called `activity_main.xml`?

Comment: the MainActivity do extend `AppCompatActivity` , and the provided layout is not `activity_main.xml` it is called `fragment_List.xml` @anatolii

Comment: I don't think this was the problem, the `fragment_list.xml` already inflated in the Fragment , i will edit the question to provide Fragment code

Comment: @evals could you share where you create your `Fragment` ?

Comment: i will post everything in minutes , just need to write comments in my code to make it clear

Comment: @evals hold on, but you call this `mBlogList = recyclee` in `ònCreate` before the `Fragment's` `onCreateView` is called.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the `findViewById` on onCreate or onCreateView (if you are in a Fragment). It is happening because before this methods your layout wasn't inflated yet so Android cannot find your RecyclerView

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

     private lateinit var mBlogList : RecyclerView

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        mBlogList = findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.recyclee)
    }
}
```

I would recommend you to read this: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/android-plugin.html
Kotlin has a better way to get the reference os your views, you don't need to use `findViewById` =)

Comment: just to make sure, are you closing the `FrameLayout ` tag?

Comment: 100% yes i closed it

Answer (score 0):

You cannot call `findViewById` from the global scope. But, you can declare it as:

```java
private val mBlogList by lazy { findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.recyclee) }
```

...then use the variable the usual.

Comment: shows another error : Missing 'setValue(MainActivity, KProperty<*>,RecyclerView!)

Answer (score 0):

In this way you could access `RecyclerView` attributes once adapter has been loaded at `onCreate()` function

```
var recyclerView : RecyclerViewAdapterYourClass = adapter as RecyclerViewAdapterYourClass 
       
recyclerView.yourRecyclerAttribute
```